# Python list syntax help

Tags: python, list

```
results=[key for key, value in adictionary if str(key).startswith('target') 
    and value > 0 ]
```

What am I trying to do here is select all the keys if the key in dictionary that beginswith target and its value is greater than 0. But looks there's a problem with this, help me~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
results=[key for key, value in adictionary.items() if str(key).startswith('target') 
             and value > 0 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing `items()` ior `iteritems()` to your dict access. `iteritems` will not create a temp list which could be slightly faster.

```
results=[key for key, value in adictionary.iteritems() if str(key).startswith('target') 
             and value > 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `items()` method to get both key and value.

```
 [key for key, value in adictionary.items() if str(key).startswith('target') and value > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the iteritems() method of the dictionary. It returns an interator rather than generating a full list like the items() method does.

`results = [key for key, value in adictionary.iteritems() if str(key).startswith('target') and value > 0]`

Comment: @Rod yeah missed that, I'd still use the iter version though.

Answer (score 0):

startswith() is slower than slicing

I would do:

```
results=[k for k,v in adictionary.iteritems()
         if (k[0:7]=='target')==True==(v>0)]
```